# How to remove memory leaks between OpenCV 1.1 and MFC 6.0 without linking MFC as static library

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc

If you ever tried to use MFC and OpenCV together, you would know [this well documented problem](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.opencv/43423). As the forum shows, without linking MFC as static library, using OpenCV creates memory leaks.

A guy, however, found a way to resolve this problem by recompiling OpenCV with slightly changed code. But it was for 2.0 or later.

I would like to know if there is a similar method for OpenCV 1.0 or 1.1. Of course, there is no system.cpp in those versions. Anybody tried this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are still using such an old version of OpenCV?

Comment: @mevatron No. I am just an antique lover. :-) It's one of restrictions our system has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Visual Studio 6.0 to test on, but I had this problem on Visual Studio 9 and what I did was the following:

I went to `Project Properties/Linker/Input` and I added to the `Delay Loaded DLLs` the following DLLs:

`opencv_core220d.dll;opencv_highgui220d.dll` in debug

`opencv_core220.dll;opencv_highgui220.dll` in release

I see [Visual Studio 6.0 has this option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx).